# Connecting LEDs to 220v without using a power supply

Tags: power-supply, led, mains

I'm designing a backlit custom picture frame, and I want to include the power supply (or the lack of one) inside the body of the frame.

The problem is, since the frame design is more or less thin, I don't have space to place a power supply, so I ran into this doubt, can I make a circuit to use a LED strip that connects directly to 220v without using a power supply?.

My knowledge of electronic is almost null, I ran into several links explaining how to power LEDs strips directly to 200v, but, I have honestly no idea what problems, advantages or disadvantages I could find, and the language used was kind of advanced for me.

Basically, I want to know if this is possible, and what is required to do so.

Please explain to me like If I'm 6 years old, thanks!.

Comment: Let me just restate Kamil's nice answer (+1). Buy a wall wart that puts out a nice safe DC voltage to power your LED's.  (Come back and ask how to hook it up.)

Comment: I would, but I need one that is thin enough to fit in there.

Comment: Can't you hide the wart somewhere, and just have wires going to the led's?

Comment: If it goes into the wall... no.

Comment: At least the pictures will be interactive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Explanation for someone who needs answer "like for 6 years old":

It is possible, you can build simple circuit for LED, but **don't do this.** Just use old phone battery charger or some external power supply because if you wont - you need **serious and robust insulation** there. This is more problematic than just using power supply and some resistor.

AC mains is not only dangerous voltage. It is also high energy source. If your frame falls, casing may break and wires connect to each other - it may cause short circuit and **fire**.

---

However - you can build very sturdy/robust casing and make sure that wires will not connect each other no matter what (hitting ground, pulling cord) - you can use `diode + 1W resistor` or `diode + capacitor + resistor` circuit as current limiter for LED (small LED, not power-LED).

Just search web for "led powered from mains" and **stay away from Instructables**. I saw many irresponsible and dangerous tutorials there. Here is one example:

[image]

Be careful with LED if it explodes. LED diodes contain [arsenic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic) which is notoriously poisonous to multicellular life.

Comment: +1 for the instructables comment.  Full of rather dodgy things written by people that really don't have the slightest clue what they're doing.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle I'm wondering why there is no "report dangerous idiot" button on Instructables. Or maybe it is visible after login.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I would honestly need some sort of step-by-step guide or tutorial to make it work :p. And, yes, I plan to insulate the strips completely.

Comment: @Artemix I have added very important information. Simple current limiters mentioned in my answer are for low current (10-20mA) LEDs, **not power LEDs**. For power leds you have to use dedicated LED power supply.

Comment: I see, I think what I'm using are power leds. Right now I'm using a strip of 5050 leds, I think that's the model.

Comment: @Artemix 5050 is just size :) Oh dear, you should avoid mains. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Design your frame around a 5v supply. This basically means an LED and a resistor in series. Connect this to a USB cable, the flat end, pins 1(power) and 4(ground). You can get the cables very cheap at any electronic gadget supplier.

While you are there getting the cable, also get a USB charger. Small, and readily available for under €10.

Building a 220v -> LED power supply that fits in a picture frame is not impossible. But it is not easy, and the development and testing of such a supply exposes lethal voltages. If you need instructions, you shouldn't be doing it. Since commercial power supplies are readily available lets just use one of them instead.

Comment: I'm interested about the USB charger idea, I will dig into it. About the power supply, I need it to be something like 1"x3-5".

Comment: USB chargers are readily available in sizes you can close your hand around. To clarify - the charger still plugs into the wall. Your cable from the frame ends in a USB plug that goes into the charger.

Comment: Oh I see, then it wont do unfortunately, since I need it to be power-supply-less.

Comment: @Artemix you asked "how do I do this" and everyone has said "don't do that". This should be a strong sign that what you want to do has serious (and dangerous) issues.

Comment: Paul, yes, I desisted of the idea of doing it. I just wanted to give it a try.